# Small build of amalgamated SQLite3 source

Tags: c, sqlite, compiler-options

I'd like to use the compiler options described [here](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html) to generate a smaller SQLite3 library. However, these options (including `-Os` it seems) expressly don't work with the amalgamated source, which is my preference. (I even tried all the same and indeed it won't work.)

Is there a good alternative to generating a smaller SQLite3 library that doesn't involve going through `sqlite3.c` and checking the dependencies?

Comment: `-Os` should work with the amalgamated source. Only the `OMIT` macros won't.

Comment: @Mat: Correct, it does work. It's not enough for me though, I could do with a smaller library still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Sqlite3 sources from their Fossil source control system for a particular version, which will give the unprocessed source, before amalgamation.  You can then run `make sqlite3.c` to create the amalgamation on your own -- and naturally, you can change the command line arguments to omit features you don't need.  Full details are on the [SQLite build instructions](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocompile.html#amal) page.  Certain Sqlite features are actually required to create the amalgamation; a non-amalgamated build can omit more.